# How to split a line and map it in pairs?

Tags: python

I am trying to transform a file into (key,value) pair.
Each line is given as

```
1 A B C D
2
3 E
4 F G
```

and I want to pair them as

```
(1,A),(1,B),(1,C),(1,D),(3,E),(4,F),(4,G)
```

I was trying to do this in python/scala but couldn't come up with a solution, unless I read the file line by line and use loop to do that.
Code in scala is :

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("input.txt")
val map = fileRDD.filter(_.split("\t").length>1).map{
    line=>
    val fields = line.split("\t")
    var i = 1;
    while(i<fields.length){
    (fields(0),fields(1))
    i=i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the 2 in your input?

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far and what is not working.

Comment: *I was trying to do this in python* - why have you used the `java` tag?

Comment: _"read the file line by line and use loop to do that"_ <-- what's wrong with that?

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java AND Python AND Scala?

Comment: Language is no bound. Help me with any language you are comfortable with.

Comment: 2 has no values to mapped to and hence it will no form any (key,value) pair.

Comment: Check out my answer below. Just a simple looping technique and line splits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a loopless Scala version:

```
def source = scala.io.Source fromFile "input.txt"
def lines = source.getLines
def tokens = lines map (_ split "\t")
def pairs = tokens flatMap (line => line.tail map (line.head -> _))
pairs.toList
```

The `source` definition should be obvious: I'm getting a `Source` to read from.

The `lines` definition returns an `Iterator[String]` for the lines in the file. Mind you, you do need to *close* `source` after use, which I don't do here.

I define `tokens` to take each line and split it. It's going to be an `Iterator[Array[String]]`, where each element in the array is a word, and each element in the iterator is an array of words for that line.

Let's rewrite `pairs` in for-comprehension format to better understand it. Note that this, below, translate into the exact same commands as the original definition:

```
def pairs = for {
  line <- tokens
  letter <- line.tail
} yield line.head -> letter
```

So, for each line, and each letter in the `tail` of the line, I return a pair of the head of the line and that tail. Remember that each line is an array of words in that line. The `line.head` is going to be the first word in the line, `line.tail` are all the other words in that line. Therefore, `letter` is going to be all the words but the first one, which is exactly what you asked for.

Going back to the original definition, the difference between a `flatMap` and a `map` is that, well, the result of `flatMap` is flattened.

The type of `pairs` is `Iterator[(String, String)]`. If I had used `map` instead of `flatMap`, the type was going to be `Iterator[Array[(String, String)]]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Please help me understand it !!

Comment: @PiyushAgal Ok, I extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can add the so called key/value pair using list comprehension, something like this:

```
with open('your_file', 'r') as f:
    result = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split(' ')
        result += [(int(line[0]), x) for x in line[1:] if x]
```

---

```
result

[(1, u'A'),
 (1, u'B'),
 (1, u'C'),
 (1, u'D'),
 (3, u'E'),
 (4, u'F'),
 (4, u'G')]
```

What you need is to loop for each line (get rid of the linefeed and spaces) and there is *NOTHING* wrong with looping the lines, grab the first element as "key" and pair (if any) with the remaining elements as "value".

Answer (score 0):

First, split your line based on the delimiter

`String[] pairs = input.split(" ");`

Then, loop over each `String` in the split you made, until you run out of pairs

```
int index = 0;
while (index + 1 < pairs.length) {

    index += 2;
}
```

We use `index+1` because we want to make sure that there is a key AND a value, not just a key. Then if you have those, add them to your map.

`map.put(pairs[index], pairs[index + 1]);`

A full example can be seen below. I used a single line, but if you are using a file with multiple lines just process each line separately like I did below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String input = "1 A B C D 2 3 E 4 F G";
    String[] pairs = input.split(" ");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    int index = 0;
    while (index + 1 < pairs.length) {
        map.put(pairs[index], pairs[index + 1]);
        index += 2;

    }

    for(Entry<String,String> en : map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(en.getKey() + " : " + en.getValue());
    }

}
```

Gives me the output:

```
3 : E
D : 2
1 : A
B : C
4 : F
```

Notice how `G` was skipped over, because there was not a value to associate with the key `G`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input

> `1 A B C D`
>   `2`
>   `3 E`
>   `4 F G`

All you need to do is grab the number and following characters for each line. Then split the characters and create a tuple for each one.

## Code

```
import re

input = '''1 A B C D
2
3 E
4 F G'''

values = []
for line in input.split('\n'):
    tokens = re.findall(r'^(\d+) (.*)$', line)
    if len(tokens) == 1 and len(tokens[0]) == 2:
        for val in tokens[0][1].split(' '):
            values.append((int(tokens[0][0]), val))
print(values)
```

## Output

> `[(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (1, 'D'), (3, 'E'), (4, 'F'), (4, 'G')]`

Answer (score 0):

`file.txt`

```
1 A B C D
2
3 E
4 F G
```

`main.py`

```
lines = open('file.txt').readlines() # open raw file
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines] # remove excess
lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines] # split lines

pairs = []

for line in lines:
    key = int(line[0]) # number key

    for char in line[1:]:
        if len(lines) > 1:
            new = (key, char) # create new pair
            pairs.append(new) # add pair to list

print pairs
```